# How to make a graph of rex values in Splunk where all data points are shown

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

In my logs I am printing out `"total_time:1.2334"` (for example). 
I am able to grab the time values with Splunk by using rex: `| rex "total_time:(?<time>.*)" |`

I want to display each total_time on a time chart (as either a line or a bar graph). However, when I try something like
`| timechart values(time)` it only shows a few of my data points (for example, only 3 columns are shown in the chart while there are 16 events).

Does anyone how I can display total_time best with the time on the Y axis and the occurrences on the X axis? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `values()` function displays the unique settings of the 'time' field, which means you'll see fewer than 16 columns if the same value of total_time appears more than once.  Try using `| timechart count by time`.